# Why bottom alignment doesn't work in v-content?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to align four texts, one in each corner (as the names indicate that). the `TopLeft` and `TopRight` are aligned in the correct place but the `BottomLeft` and `BottomRight` are just below them and not on the bottom of the page..

```html
 <v-content>
      <v-container fluid fill-height >
        <v-row align='start'>
          <v-col cols='1'>
            <p>TopLeft</p>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols='10'>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols='1'>
            <p>TopRight</p>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row align='end'>
          <v-col cols='1'>
            <p>BottomLeft</p>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols='10'>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols='1'>
            <p>BottomRight</p>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo. It should be `fill-height` instead of `full-height`.

Edit 1:

`align` is aligning the content of the row only. you have to align also the rows with `align-self`:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<v-app>
<v-content>
      <v-container fluid fill-height>
        <v-row align='start' class="align-self-start">
          <v-col cols='1'>
            <p>TopLeft</p>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols='10'>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols='1'>
            <p>TopRight</p>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
        <v-row align='end' class="align-self-end">
          <v-col cols='1'>
            <p>BottomLeft</p>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols='10'>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols='1'>
            <p>BottomRight</p>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Right. But it didn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Edited the answer. Hope it helps.